Accumulation Target in Flow Accumulation (Top Down) algorithm in SAGA
In version 2.2.3 and earlier of SAGA, the Flow Accumulation (Top Down) algorithm only required the (filled) DEM (Elevation) to run. There were a number of other optional inputs, including Accumulation Target, but the algorithm would run fine without these.
https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.3/ta_hydrology_0.html
From version 2.3.0 on, there is an additional required input - Accumulation Target - which is a grid. However, I have not been able to find any documentation as to what the Accumulation Target represents.

https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/ta_hydrology_0.html
Are you able to explain what the Accumulation Target represents, or point me to documentation on it?
